# Entity Framework Finding Entity via Foreign Keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

I'm assuming this is bread & butter for most..

I have Roles, Permissions, and a RolePermissions entity to model many-to-many relationship.

```
public class RolePermission
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //[Key, ForeignKey("Role"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    //[Key, ForeignKey("Permission"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PermissionID { get; set; }

    //Navigational Properties
    public virtual Role role { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission permission { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ActionResult to remove a given RolePermission, based on the RoleID and PermissionId that are passed in.

```
public ActionResult Remove(int Roleid, int Permissionid)
{
  RolePermission rolepermission = db.RolePermissions
    .Include(p => p.PermissionID == Permissionid)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.RoleID == Roleid);

  db.RolePermissions.Remove(rolepermission);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

The above RolePermission rolepermission.. statement fails with

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path
```

.. which I'm not suprised, as it has one hell of a code smell to start with.

What I'm after is the equivalent of

```
Delete from RolePermission
Where RoleID = roleid
AND PermissionID = permissionid
```

Any guidance?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the `RolePermission` exposed as an entity (which is a bit unusual for a many-to-many relationship) you should be able to just query for the record in the join table and delete it:

```
public ActionResult Remove(int Roleid, int Permissionid)
{
    RolePermission rolepermission = db.RolePermissions
        .SingleOrDefault(rp => rp.RoleID == Roleid
                            && rp.PermissionID == Permissionid);

    if (rolepermission != null)
    {
        db.RolePermissions.Remove(rolepermission);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after for - thanks. 


re: "which is a bit unusual for a many-to-many relationship". I'm creating a new front end (via code first) prototype to ultimately re-hitch up with an existing back end / data layer which has these entities. Why is this not seen as correct? 
I'm from a db background  which probably explains my thinking...

Comment: @Fetchezlavache: If your link table has a composite primary key consisting of `RoleID` and `PermissionID` and no additional column except those two, you can work with the `Role` (with direct collection of `Permissions`) and `Permission` (with direct collection of `Roles`) entity alone. `RolePermission` would not be required in your model. See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx, section *Many-to-Many Associations*, the example of `Item` and `Category`.